# Django - ModelForm - initial value

Tags: django, modelform

I'm working with Modelforms and would like to set the initial value of the "feeder" field. I get the following Type Error: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'" What might be the problem?

Many thanks all

forms.py:

```
class CashFlowForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = models.CashFlow
    fields = ['type', 'amount', 'description','date']
    widgets = {'date': DatePicker()}
```

views.py:

```
def create_cashflow(request, fundslug):

 funddetail = Fund.objects.get(slug=fundslug)

 if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = CashFlowForm(request.POST)
    cf.feeder = funddetail.feeder
    if cf.is_valid():
        instance_cf = cf.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Cash Flow successfully added!')
        return redirect('funds:create_cashflow', fundslug = fundslug) 
 else:
    cf = CashFlowForm()

 return render(request, 'funds/create_cashflow.html', {'cf': cf})
```

Comment: Which line throwing the exception?

Comment: I believe you're getting `None` for `amount` field

Comment: Also, when you say the initial value of the `feeder` field, do you mean initial when the form is displayed or set a value before saving the form?

If it's the former, `feeder` field is not displayed for the form as it is not in `fields `inside ModelForm Meta. If it's the later, then you might want to do:
`cf.save(commit=False)` before

Comment: hi Dev. it is the latter indeed. I'm trying some things but problem is dat fund detail is related to Fund and not to CashFlow model

Comment: post your `CashFlow` model class for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I fink **funddetail.feeder** return None or You can try

```
cf.cleaned_data['feeder'] = funddetail.feeder
```

Answer (score 0):

Models don't matter unless there's a foreign key involved. For the Type Error, it's mostly to do with the value your model fields are getting from the form.

For assigning value after form submission, do something like

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = CashFlowForm(request.POST)
    cf.save(commit=False)
    cf.feeder = funddetail.feeder
    cf.save()
```